# Google apps script duplicate and rename a tab and to get the last tab name +1

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using this code to duplicate a Template tab

```
function cloneGoogleSheet() {

  var name = "New";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Temp').copyTo(ss);

  /* Before cloning the sheet, delete any previous copy */
  var old = ss.getSheetByName(name);
  if (old) ss.deleteSheet(old); // or old.setName(new Name);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Utilities.sleep(2000);
  sheet.setName('1');

  /* Make the new sheet active */
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);

}
```

I want to take the last tab name, which for all my tabs are numbers, and rename the duplicated tab +1

For example if my last tab is the tab 8, when I run the script I want to have my Temp tab duplicated and named 9

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my understanding:

- You want to set the sheet name of the inserted sheet by adding `1` to the last tab name.

  - As a test case, when the last tab name is `8`, you want to set `9` to the inserted sheet.

#### Modification points:

- In this modification, at first, all existing sheets are retrieved and the last sheet name is retrieved.
- After the new sheet was inserted as the copy, the sheet name is set by adding `1` to the last sheet name.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
function cloneGoogleSheet() {
  var name = "New";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var lastTabName = ss.getSheets().pop().getSheetName();  // Modified

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Temp').copyTo(ss);
  var old = ss.getSheetByName(name);
  if (old) ss.deleteSheet(old);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  sheet.setName(isNaN(lastTabName) ? 1 : Number(lastTabName) + 1);  // Modified

  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this case, it supposes that the last sheet name in your Spreadsheet is the number. If the last sheet name is not the number, this script uses `1` as the sheet name. If you want to change it, please modify the script. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)
- [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)